# Displaying error message after validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a modal form that allows a user to input a start reading and an end reading, I have set it to validate that the end reading should not be lower than the start. When the form is submitted, the modal disappears and the validation works as the record is not added but no error message is displayed. Is there any way to show an error message in the modal before the user submits?
I tried to use a class inside the text field but it still does not show a message.

Validation code:

```
 $request->validate([
            'start_odo' => 'required',
            'end_odo' => 'required|gt:start_odo|',
        ]);
```

View:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
                <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Start ODO</label>
                <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="start_odo" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="0" required>
              
              </div>
            
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">End ODO</label>
                <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="end_odo" class="form-control @error('end_odo') is-invalid @enderror" id="recipient-name" min="0"  required>
                @error('end_odo')
                <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
   
              </div>
```

Comment: use javascript, jquery or any frontend framework for it

Comment: you can use livewire. its simple and gives you ajax experience.

Comment: @bhucho how would I do that?

Comment: [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/pjoter-2-0/1094165#js-tab-view) is a simple example for validate.js usage, you can watch some tutorials to see how to do it from scratch via js

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about two ways to do that.

First is **Ajax**.
You can send the form data via ajax and you'll get your validation errors as response. So you know what to print in js.

Second is **Frontend validation library**.
So you will validate data via javascript on frontend side. But be sure to validate data once again on backend. It is so important.
example lib. could be: https://validatejs.org/

Comment: How could OI do that?